# Create a categorized DataFrame from a Pandas list that includes Brand & Model name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame of car brand names & car models in 1 column, car price in 1 column that looks like below.

```
car_name          car_price
BMW M50           50000
Tesla Model 3     14000
BMW M3 Series     20500
Mercedes G500     45000
Mercedes E200     12300
```

How can I categorize the car_name column so that there are 3 columns in the DataFrame that would look like below:

```
car_brand       car_model        car_price
BMW             M50              50000
Tesla           Model 3          14000
BMW             M3 Series        20500
Mercedes        G500             45000
Mercedes        E200             12300
```

I also have the list that specifically includes only car_brand names like:

```
[Mercedes, BMW, Hyundai, KIA, Tesla, Chevrolet]
```

So how do I tell Pandas DataFrame to group all the rows in car_name column into a car_brand and car_model columns? Provided that the first part of the car_name column data will always be the car_brand while the 2nd part of the car_name data will always be the car_model

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
car_brand =['Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Hyundai', 'KIA', 'Tesla', 'Chevrolet']
pat=r'({})'.format('|'.join(car_brand))
#'(Mercedes|BMW|Hyundai|KIA|Tesla|Chevrolet)'
```

---

```
df['car_brand']=df.car_name.str.extract(pat)
df['car_model']=df.pop('car_name').str.replace(pat,'').str.strip()
```

---

```
print(df)

   car_price car_brand  car_model
0      50000       BMW        M50
1      14000     Tesla    Model 3
2      20500       BMW  M3 Series
3      45000  Mercedes       G500
4      12300  Mercedes       E200
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Can you please explain or share a link where I can understand the code more in depth? Specifically this part:

pat=r'({})'.format('|'.join(car_brand))

Comment: @NijatBehbudov `'|'.join(car_brand)` joins a list(if you just print this) with a pipe. Then we are binding it in a tuple if you see the examples [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :) I find [this](https://pyformat.info/) good for  format.

Comment: when I add many items into car_brand list, python throws an error: "Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1"

Actual list is longer than this: 
car_brand =['Acura', 'Alfa Romeo', 'Aston Martin', 'ATV', 'Audi', 'Baic', 'Bentley', 'BMC', 'BMW', 'BMW Alpina', 'Brilliance', 'Buick', 'BYD', 'Cadillac', 'Can-Am', 'Changan', 'Chery', 'Chevrolet', 'Chrysler', 'Citroen', 'Dacia', 'Daewoo', 'DAF', 'Daihatsu', 'Dayun', 'Dnepr', 'Dodge', 'DongFeng', 'FAW', 'Ferrari', 'Fiat', 'Ford', 'Foton', 'Gabro', 'GAC', 'GAZ', 'Geely', 'GMC', 'Great Wall', 'Haojue', 'Harley-Davidson']

Comment: @NijatBehbudov i tested the test dataframe you have provided with the big list(you just gave) and it works fine. I think this is a seperate issue , check the line where you receive the error and try debugging/post another question(if you like)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
car_brand =['Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Hyundai', 'KIA', 'Tesla', 'Chevrolet']
pat=r'({})'.format('|'.join(car_brand)) + '(.+)'

df[['car_brand','car_model']] = df.pop('car_name').str.extract(pat)
print (df)
   car_price car_brand   car_model
0      50000       BMW         M50
1      14000     Tesla     Model 3
2      20500       BMW   M3 Series
3      45000  Mercedes        G500
4      12300  Mercedes        E200
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Can you please explain or share a link where I can understand the code more in depth? Specifically the "pat=r'({})'.format('|'.join(car_brand)) + '(.+)'" part was not clear to me. Thanks

Comment: @NijatBehbudov - super, so I think explanation get from accepted answerer, so wait for `anky_91`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.column.apply` method with `lambda` functions here:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{
    ...:         "car_name": "BMW M50",
    ...:         "car_price": "50000"
    ...:     },
    ...:     {
    ...:         "car_name": "Tesla Model 3",
    ...:         "car_price": "14000"
    ...:     },
    ...:     {
    ...:         "car_name": "BMW M3 Series",
    ...:         "car_price": "20500"
    ...:     },
    ...:     {
    ...:         "car_name": "Mercedes G500",
    ...:         "car_price": "45000"
    ...:     },
    ...:     {
    ...:         "car_name": "Mercedes E200",
    ...:         "car_price": "12300"
    ...:     }])
df

        car_name car_price
0        BMW M50     50000
1  Tesla Model 3     14000
2  BMW M3 Series     20500
3  Mercedes G500     45000
4  Mercedes E200     12300


df["car_brand"] = df.car_name.apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
df["car_model"] = df.car_name.apply(lambda x: x.split(" ",1)[1])

df
        car_name car_price car_brand  car_model
0        BMW M50     50000       BMW        M50
1  Tesla Model 3     14000     Tesla    Model 3
2  BMW M3 Series     20500       BMW  M3 Series
3  Mercedes G500     45000  Mercedes       G500
4  Mercedes E200     12300  Mercedes       E200
```

Comment: Emil, thanks for your response.
However, with your code 2-worded car brand names wouldn't work. For example if the car_name was "Aston Martin DB11". This code would make the "Aston" as car_brand while the "Martin DB11" part would be the car_model. 

That's why I have created a different list of specific car brand names so the code can recognize if "Aston" is really a car brand or not. Good trick though. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Also the same could be done by using re.split():

```
import re

df['car_model']=df['car_name'].apply(lambda x: re.split('|'.join(car_brand), x)[1])
```